# Angular - How to remove <style> element from <head> after the component is destroyed

Tags: angular

> Note: I tried the example in both Angular 5 and Angular 6.

## The issue

If using `'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None'` on an Angular component a `<style>` element will be appended to the `<head>` when component is being shown. The `<style>` element will never get removed, even after the component is destroyed. This is the issue.
As more components are shown there are more and more `<style>` elements in the `<head>`. Ultimately this causes conflicts when there are global css rules for the same html element e.g. `body`, as per my example. Only the CSS from the lastly appended `<style>`  block will be used, even if this last `<style>` block belongs to the component that does not exist anymore.

[image: head styles]

I would like to see a proper solution for removing from the DOM the `<style>` element that came along with some component. E.g. cleanup when `onDestoy` function from the component is triggered.

I am new to Angular and I have just stumbled upon this interesting behavior. Would be good to know if there is a simple workaround.

---

## Example

EXAMPLE:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukkecu

[image: Angular example]

In my app I have 3 wrapper components that will be the root element of my app. Only one would be shown at the time. Shown component will determine the theme for the entire website. It should include global styles, more specifically a dedicated variant of a global style (a theme). For that reason they all have `'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None'`. Each global style have it's own compiled variant of bootstrap and other external plugins based on SASS variables. So having encapsulation here is no option, these are global styles and plugins.

The solution works fine the first time only until the other components are shown and `<style>` elements are appended to the `<head>`. After that only the styles from the lastly used component will be used because its `<style>` came last and overrides any previous styles.

---

## Possible solutions

It seems like the only solution would be to reload the page, or not use components for switching the global theme.

Comment: If you are downvoting I'd be happy to hear the reason too. I clearly described the issue and set the live example

Comment: You shouldn't use a loaded component to write the global theme. Let a service (on app level) handle that. The components can inform the service about what to do, if you want.

Comment: So the service should compile sass files and inject global styles?

Comment: No, whatever component manages `body` uses the service as well, but to dynamically set the style (by using classes or directly in the template or whatever). Just like any other component styles itself.

Comment: Here's a quickly hacked together stackblitz that demonstrates it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r7cjiy

Comment: Sorry I can't see ,much here on stackblitz. Could you verify you posted the correct link? And thanks for re-framing my issue. Yes I need different styles which manages body but have different colors. It's basically separate compiled bootstrap in each theme

Comment: Sorry, the link was indeed wrong. Here's a working one: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agve9a It does differ a bit from what exactly you want, but it just demonstrates the technique.

Comment: I've updated the example now to not require you to hook into the actual body element. You can just use `Renderer2` and `document.body`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and a good idea. I was thinking of switching the body class but the problem here is that I don't have a control over the css file. I want to have three separate bootstrap builds each would use a different scss variables. That's why having a different class on a body would not work. I literately need a solution to change an entire compiled css file. Maybe this is also achievable with the service you have created, to append <link> into <head> and later to remove it? If yes, I can accept this as a solution here as an answer. I think I understand component way was wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Forget about `encapsulation` in your case, it can't help you with your requirement. Instead use a shared service, lets call it *style-service*, that will add/remove the style nodes in the document head.

Instead of adding your css styles in the `stylesUrls` of the `@Component` decorator, you will add them by using the *style-service* on `ngOnInit` function, which will add the style node to the document head. Once the component gets destroyed on `ngOnDestroy` function, you will remove the style by using the *style-service*, which will remove the style node from the document head.

Enough said, lets see some code:

**style.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StyleService {
  private stylesMap: Map<any, Node> = new Map();
  private host: Node;

  constructor() {
    this.host = document.head;
  }

  private createStyleNode(content: string): Node {
    const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
    styleEl.textContent = content;
    return styleEl;
  }

  addStyle(key: any, style: string): void {
    const styleEl = this.createStyleNode(style);
    this.stylesMap.set(key, styleEl);
    this.host.appendChild(styleEl);
  }

  removeStyle(key: any): void {
    const styleEl = this.stylesMap.get(key);
    if (styleEl) {
      this.stylesMap.delete(key);
      this.host.removeChild(styleEl);
    }
  }
}
```

**WrapperVariantRedComponent** (from your demo)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

import { StyleService } from '../style.service';

declare const require: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wrapper-variant-red',
  templateUrl: './wrapper-variant-red.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './wrapper-variant-red.component.css']
})
export class WrapperVariantRedComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private styleService: StyleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.styleService.addStyle('red-theme', require('../../theme/global-theme-variant-red.css'));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.styleService.removeStyle('red-theme');
  }

}
```

Working (forked) [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-theme-service) from your StackBlitz sample.

Comment: You could use the `HeadService` from `@bespunky/angular-zen` to do this:
https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/additional-documentation/coremodule/headservice.html

It's very flexible and easy to use.

Comment: it works fine for pure CSS, but is there any solution that works when using SASS files for styling?

Comment: @Lars that's a good question! unfortunately I don't know the answer for that, I'll have to dig deeper to find one. If you'll find an answer I'll be happy if you could share it. Thanks