# Angular 8 - How to remove <style> element from <head> after the component is destroyed

Tags: angular, angular8

[Angular - How to remove  element from  after the component is destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311141/angular-how-to-remove-style-element-from-head-after-the-component-is-destr?newreg=70323db893d64caaa238dfa1588cec88)

I am following the solution above but i cannot get the css to be shown correctly.

It returns me **[object module]** rather than the css contents when i add:

component.ts

```
this.styleService.addStyle('usergrid1css', require('../../../assets/css/clr.css'));
```

html

```
<style>[object module]</style>
```

Anybody can help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

[chrome devtools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVevg.png)

```
code below extracted from the url above

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StyleService {
  private stylesMap: Map<any, Node> = new Map();
  private host: Node;

  constructor() {
    this.host = document.head;
  }

  private createStyleNode(content: string): Node {
    console.log('style');
    const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
    styleEl.textContent = content;
    return styleEl;
  }

  addStyle(key: any, style: string): void {
    const styleEl = this.createStyleNode(style);
    this.stylesMap.set(key, styleEl);
    this.host.appendChild(styleEl);
  }

  removeStyle(key: any): void {
    const styleEl = this.stylesMap.get(key);
    if (styleEl) {
      this.stylesMap.delete(key);
      this.host.removeChild(styleEl);
    }
  }
}


**component.ts**


import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { concat, merge, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { StyleService } from '../../services/style.service';

declare function require(name: string): any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private styleService: StyleService) {
  }
ngOnInit() {

    this.styleService.addStyle('usergrid1css', require('./clr.css'));

}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show a lot more code than just those 2 lines. Show us your `StyleService` code and the component code that is using it.

Comment: `require` returns a module, not text. You’ll need to get the text from that module, or find a different way of getting the CSS (like via Ajax).

Comment: this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-theme-service) works well with require. @HereticMonkey

Comment: If you’re using someone else’s code, it’s probably a good idea to give them credit in the question... All I can tell you is what I see from the code you’ve decided to share with us.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes but how do I tagged them here?

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by my answer is based on this angular service obtained in the [github repository of material.angular.io](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/style-manager/style-manager.ts)

I also leave an example running in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-to-remove-style-element-from-head-after-the-compo) of the use of said service

service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Class for managing stylesheets. Stylesheets are loaded into named slots so that they can be
 * removed or changed later.
 */
@Injectable()
export class StyleManagerService {

  /**
   * Set the stylesheet with the specified key.
   */
  setStyle(key: string, href: string) {
    getLinkElementForKey(key).setAttribute('href', href);
  }

  /**
   * Remove the stylesheet with the specified key.
   */
  removeStyle(key: string) {
    const existingLinkElement = getExistingLinkElementByKey(key);
    if (existingLinkElement) {
      document.head.removeChild(existingLinkElement);
    }
  }

}

function getLinkElementForKey(key: string) {
  return getExistingLinkElementByKey(key) || createLinkElementWithKey(key);
}

function getExistingLinkElementByKey(key: string) {
  return document.head.querySelector(`link[rel="stylesheet"].${getClassNameForKey(key)}`);
}

function createLinkElementWithKey(key: string) {
  const linkEl = document.createElement('link');
  linkEl.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
  linkEl.classList.add(getClassNameForKey(key));
  document.head.appendChild(linkEl);
  return linkEl;
}

function getClassNameForKey(key: string) {
  return `style-manager-${key}`;
}
```

component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnDestroy  {
  themes = [
    'deeppurple-amber',
    'indigo-pink',
    'pink-bluegrey',
    'purple-green'
  ];

  constructor(public _styleManager: StyleManagerService) {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    removeTheme();
  }

  selectTheme(themeName: string) {
    this._styleManager.setStyle('theme', `assets/${themeName}.css`);
  }

  removeTheme() {
    this._styleManager.removeStyle('theme');
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `HeadService` from `@bespunky/angular-zen` to do this:
https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/additional-documentation/coremodule/headservice.html

It's very flexible and easy to use...